# How to force android service to be destroyed?

Tags: android, service

I execute `stopSelf` as service finishes working (from within service) but it is not destroyed (see using log output in `onDestroy()`) right after it. It leads that `startService` uses existing (stopped) service instead of starting new one. How can i force service to be destroyed right after it is stopped?

Comment: probably, android decided not to stop service as it has references or smth. Does anyone know what prevents it from destroying?

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation:

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with
>   the **Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE** flag. Once neither of these
>   situations hold, the service's **onDestroy**() method is called and
>   the service is effectively terminated.